# E is measurable set , is {$\sqrt x|x∈E$} measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

E is Lebesgue measurable subset of [0,1], is {$\sqrt x|x∈E$ } Lebesgue measurable subset of [0,1]?

First,I want to use lipschitz to prove it.But $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is not lipschitz on [0,1] and I can't find the counterexample.

Can you give me some suggestion.Thank you!!!

Comment: Is $E$ Borel measurable or Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Lebesgue measurable

Comment: special case of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209345/lebesgue-measuarable-sets-under-a-differentiable-bijection)

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge1$ let $E_n = E \cap [\frac1n,1]$. Then, since $f$ is Lipschitz on $[\frac1n,1]$, the set $\sqrt{E_n}$ is measurable. Therefore $\sqrt E \setminus\{0\} = \big( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{E_n} \big)$ is also measurable (and the single point $0$ won't ruin that if it's in $E$).

Comment: is $\sqrt E = \big( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{E_n} \big) \setminus\{0\}$  or $\sqrt E \setminus\{0\}= \big( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{E_n} \big) $ ?

Comment: You are right about that!