# $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is a Nullset then $f(A)$ is also a Nullset

Tags: measure-theory

As shown on title for a function continuous differentiable $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R^n} $ holds:
$A \subseteq  \mathbb{R^n}$ is a Nullset then $f(A)$ is also a Nullset.

What can be idea to show this statement?

Comment: This is not correct. There are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself that map the Cantor set to a set with positive measure.

Comment: @HansEngler I've forgotten to write that f is continuous differentiable!

Comment: Since $f(\bigcup_n E_n)=\bigcup_n f(E_n)$, you can localize the statement, namely, assume that the derivative is bounded. In this case, the map doesn't enlarge domains a lot (the ratio is related to the bound of the derivative). Could you elaborate a proof?

Comment: @FrankScience No, because I haven't understood well the concept! :(

Comment: For the moment, you can do the following exercises: Assume first that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, namely there exists $M>0$ such that for each $x,y$, we have $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\le M\lvert x-y\rvert$ (we take the Euclidean norm). 1. There's a constant $C$ that only depends on $M$, such that for each closed ball $B$, we have the outer measure of $f(B)$ is no larger than $C$ times the volume of $B$; 2. Do the same for cubes; 3. Conclude; 4. Now assume that $f$ is a general continuously differentiable function. Write $\mathbb R^n$ as a countable union, and conclude.

Answer (score 2):

The argument consists of three steps, as outlined by [Frank Science](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524812/a-subseteq-mathbbrn-is-a-nullset-then-fa-is-also-a-nullset#comment3108666_1524812).

1. Restrict attention to the ball $B_n=\{x:\|x\|\le n\}$, and observe that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $B$ (since its gradient is bounded there).
2. Apply the result that Lipschitz maps preserve sets of measure zero: see [Why does a Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ map measure zero sets to measure zero sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139883/why-does-a-lipschitz-function-f-mathbbrd-to-mathbbrd-map-measure-zero-s)
3. Countable union of sets of measure zero also has measure zero, and $f(A)=\bigcup_n f(A\cap B_n)$.