# Lipschitz function maps set of measure zero to set of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let the function $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Lipschitz, that is, there is a constant $c \geq 0$ such that for
all $u, v \in [a, b]$, $|f( u) - f( v)| \le c |u - v|$. Show that $f$ maps a set of measure zero onto a
set of measure zero.

The following is my attempt:

Suppose that $A \subseteq [0,1]$ has measure zero and $\varepsilon > 0$ be given.
    By definition of measure, there exists a countable collection of open intervals $\{ I_k \}_{k \geq 1}$ such that $A \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}{I_k}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{l(I_k)} < \frac{\varepsilon}{c}. $
    Note that $f(A) \subseteq f(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}{I_k}) = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}{f(I_k)}.$
    For each $k$, denote $I_k = (x_k, y_k).$
    Since $f$ is Lipschitz, for each $k$, $|f(x_k) - f(y_k)| \leq c \cdot |x_k - y_k|.$
    Therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{|f(x_k) - f(y_k)|} \leq c \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{|x_k - y_k|} < \varepsilon.$
    Hence, $f(A)$ has measure zero.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139883/why-does-a-lipschitz-function-f-mathbbrd-to-mathbbrd-map-measure-zero-s) is essentially your own.

Comment: @Idonknow I think your answer is not correct. What is $f(I_k)$ and how did you estimate its measure. (It is an interval by IVP but you have to say what the end points are).  If $f$ is monotonic you can write down the end points of $f(I_k)$, but you have to fill in some details when $f$ is not monotonic.