# if $m(A)=0$ then $m(A^2)=0$ .$m$ is Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $m$ is [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) on $\mathbb{R}$ now which of following options is true?

1. if A be uncountable then $m(A)>0$
2. if $m(A)>0$ then $A^{\circ} \neq \varnothing$
3. if $m(A)=0$ then $m(A^2)=0$ . (note that $A^{2}=\left\{a^{2} \mid a \in A\right\}$)
4. $m(A+B)=m(A)+m(B)$ (note that $A+B=\{a+b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$ )

counterexample for 1 and 4 ,$A=B= $[Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) and for 2 ,$[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}^{\mathrm{c}}$. how we can proof "3" ?

Comment: Just apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139883/why-does-a-lipschitz-function-f-mathbbrd-to-mathbbrd-map-measure-zero-s) with the function $f(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute\begin{align*}
m(A^2) &= \int 1_{A^2}(x) \:dx \\
&= \int 1_{|A|}(\sqrt{x}) \: dx \\
&= \int_{|A|} 2u \: du \quad (\text{substitution with $u=\sqrt{x}$})
\end{align*}

and then note that $m(|A|) \leq m(A) + m(-A) = 2m(A) = 0$, so the above integral is over a set of measure $0$ and we conclude $m(A^2)=0$.

Comment: What is $|A|$ ?

Comment: I guess i should have added a definition, but i simply mean $|A|:=\{|x| \: | \: x\in A\}$.